# Should I avoid casting a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I have a method in C that expects a double pointer as an argument:

```
void method(
    // in/out
    double *dOne,
    ...)
```

The caller has a float pointer

```
float *fOne;
```

What is a good way call `method()` with `fOne`?

```
method((double*)fOne, ...);
```

is not the best, is it?

Comment: There are no methods in C.  C only has functions.

Comment: Casting a `float*` to a `double*` will not work for this. Depending on what is really being done, perhaps: `double temp = *fOne; method(&temp,...);*fOne = temp;`.  You could wrap that in a function named something like `void fmethod(float* pf);`

Comment: If the function wants a `double *`, then you need to pass it a genuine `double *`.  You can convert to/from `float` outside of the function.

Comment: It's easier to understand why this wont work if you know that typically a `float` is 32 bits of data, and `double` is 64 bits of data. If you have an array of, say, five `float` elements (that is 20 bytes), then casting that to `double *` will not create an array of five `double` elements (which would be 40 bytes).

Comment: Thanks to all. I think Michael Burr's comment is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should never cast pointers of different types. When the pointed-to types have different representations, such forced conversions simply don't make any sense. For example, `double` and `float` might not have the same size or representation, in which case pointer conversions between the two types are blatantly incorrect.

But even if you *know* that the different types have the same representation, the pointer conversion is *still* not safe! Because of the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule), such conversions might yield incorrectly generated code by the compiler, since the compiler is free to assume that you would never access the given data through a pointer of an incorrect type. So it might optimize away portions of your code.

It is only safe to cast any given pointer:

- To/from a pointer pointing at the same qualified type (*).
- To a pointer pointing at the same type, but with more qualifiers specified (*).
- To/from `void` pointer.
- To a null pointer.
- To a pointer to byte integer types, such as `char*` or `uint8_t*`.

All other cases of pointer to pointer conversions are bugs and invoke undefined behavior as soon as you access the pointed-to data. Including casts *from* `char*` to a pointer to a larger type.

---

(*) Qualified type means, a type with qualifiers such as `const` or `volatile` present. For example it is safe to convert from `int*` to `const int*` but never the other way around.

Comment: Note that is also "safe" (in the sense that you mean) to cast *back* from a `char *` to the original type.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Well... it is safe to convert from for example `int*` to `bananas*` and then back to `int*`, without ever accessing the data through the `bananas` pointer. Why you would do that though, I have no idea.

Comment: Well in the `char *` case, the cast to `char *` is explicitly allowed in order to do byte-by-byte operations.  But at some point you need to get back to the original type, which is also safe!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Well... yes... no... maybe :) It is safe if you don't modify the pointed-at address. But if you do, whether it is safe or dangerous depends on alignment.